# Retrieving all months / days within two dates?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, charts, ms-access-2010, oledb

I have two DateTimePickers and a chart, and at the bottom of the chart's legend will determine the months between the two DateTimePickers and retrieve all the data when they were created.

Example:

**DateTimePicker1 = February**

**DateTimePicker2 = June**

1. Retrieve all the data from Feb. to Jun.
2. Chart should show **February, March, April, May, June** at the
   bottom legend.

How do I do this? Or at least just getting all the months within two DateTimePickers?

Comment: do you have any code to show what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the information about month names stored in the CultureInfo.
Here I use the InvariantCulture but this could be applied also to your current culture

```
Dim m1 = "February"
Dim m2 = "June"
Dim idx1 = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames.ToList().IndexOf(m1)
Dim idx2 = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames.ToList().IndexOf(m2)

' An array of strings with the months names required by the interval.    
Dim monthsList = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames _ 
                            .SkipWhile(Function(mn, i) i < idx1) _ 
                            .TakeWhile(Function(mm, i) i < (idx2-idx1)) _ 
                            .ToArray()

' A comma separated string with the months names
Dim monthsLabel = String.Join(",", monthsList)
```

To obtain the month names from the DateTimePicker value use

```
Dim m1 = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames(dp1.Value.Month - 1)
```